# jquery on select drop down push data to label element

Tags: jquery

I have the following select drop down. I'm trying to figure out how to create a jquery script that'll correspond a message from the select value to the `<label class="vfb-desc">` replacing `Instructions` when choosing an item from the select drop-down.

```
    <select name="vfb-16" id="vfb-16" class="vfb-select  vfb-medium  required ">       
    <option value="Select Credit Card type">Select Credit Card type</option>
    <option value="Visa">Visa</option>
    <option value="MasterCard">MasterCard</option>
    <option value="Discover">Discover</option>
    <option value="America Express">America Express</option>
    </select>


<li class="vfb-item vfb-item-instructions  " id="item-vfb-37">
 <label class="vfb-desc"></label>
</li>
```

**This is what I've tried:**

```
var newLabel = '';
$('#vfb-16').on('change', function(){

$('#item-vfb-37 label').text(newLabel); //Change the text before changing the value
switch(this.value){
    case 'Visa':
        newLabel = 'Interest';
        break;
    case 'MasterCard':
        newLabel = 'Future value';
        break;
    case 'Discover':
        newLabel = 'Present value';
        break;
    case 'American Express':
        newLabel = 'Payment';
        break;
}

}).trigger('change');

<li class="vfb-item vfb-item-instructions  " id="item-vfb-37">
 <label class="vfb-desc"></label>
</li>
```

For some reason when I choose the drop down value, the results form `newLabel` doesn't match when placed in the `<label class="vfb-desc"></label>` container.

**Updated Code:**

```
    <select name="vfb-16" id="vfb-16" class="vfb-select  vfb-medium  required ">       
    <option value="Select Credit Card type">Select Credit Card type</option>
    <option value="Visa">Visa</option>
    <option value="MasterCard">MasterCard</option>
    <option value="Discover">Discover</option>
    <option value="America Express">America Express</option>
    </select>

<li class="vfb-item vfb-item-instructions  " id="item-vfb-37">
 <label class="vfb-desc"></label>
</li>


var newLabel = '';
$('#vfb-16').on('change', function(){


switch(this.value){
    case 'Visa':
        newLabel = 'Interest';
        break;
    case 'MasterCard':
        newLabel = 'Future value';
        break;
    case 'Discover':
        newLabel = 'Present value';
        break;
    case 'Amex':
        newLabel = 'Payment';
        break;
}

}).trigger('change');

$('#item-vfb-37 label').text(newLabel); //Change the text before changing the value
```

**Final Code:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var newLabel = '';
    $('#vfb-16').on('change', function(){

    switch(this.value){
        case 'Visa':
            newLabel = '<a href="https://www.odysseyxxxx.com/terms-and-conditions-visa" target="_new">Terms and Conditions visa</a>';
            break;
        case 'MasterCard':
            newLabel = '<a href="https://www.odysseyxxxx.com/terms-and-conditions-master" target="_new">Terms and Conditions mastercard</a>';
            break;
        case 'Discover':
            newLabel = '<a href="https://www.odysseyxxxx.com/terms-and-conditions-dis" target="_new">Terms and Conditions discovery</a>';
            break;
        case 'Amex':
            newLabel = '<a href="https://www.odysseyxxxx.com/terms-and-conditions-amex" target="_new">Terms and Conditions amex</a>';
            break;
    }

    $('#item-vfb-37 label').html(newLabel); //Change the text/html value after choosing select option
});

<select name="vfb-16" id="vfb-16" class="vfb-select  vfb-medium  required valid">
 <option value="Select Credit Card type">Select Credit Card type</option>       
 <option value="Visa">Visa</option><option value="MasterCard">MasterCard</option>
 <option value="Discover">Discover</option>
 <option value="Amex">Amex</option>
</select>

<li class="vfb-item vfb-item-instructions  " id="item-vfb-37">
 <label class="vfb-desc"></label>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple example:

```
$('#vfb-16').on('change', function() {
    $('#item-vfb-37 label').text($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: ty with your help I've modified my code to reflect this change $('#item-vfb-37 label').text(newLabel)

Comment: lol, take a look at my question I've updated. I'm having other issues.

Comment: Why do you change the text before changing the value? What you practically do now is, when you change the value to populate the label with the previously selected option. You should move $('#item-vfb-37 label').text(newLabel); after the switch clause.

Comment: by placing the code to the correct line worked. I've accepted your answer. ty.